# Why is JavaScript onload not working?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want my animation to display only when the page loads, so that there is no static image shown while page loads.

The following is the JavaScript code:

```
function start() {
setObjVis('myobj','visible');
}
window.onload = start;
```

Following is CSS code:

```
#my_animation{
animation: mymove 10s 1;
position: relative;
visibility: hidden;
}
```

Following is HTML code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src='js/script.js'></script>
.
.
.
<img src="img/animation_image.png" alt="Animation" height="550px" id="my_animation" />
```

However, my animation image is hidden. I understand that the    visibility:hidden of CSS has caused it to become hidden. But JavaScript is not making it visible.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is `setObjVis`? It's often better to define a `hidden` class instead and remove that class from the classlist when you don't want to hide the element anymore.

Comment: Hi Sebastian.

I came across the setObjVis function here: http://javascript.about.com/library/blanim02.htm

Comment: I am a little new here. Can someone tell me why I'm getting so many downvotes?

Comment: Probably because you didn't provide the `setObjVis` function in your question, so people have to guess what is going wrong in there.

Comment: I thought it might have been an inbuilt function, sorry. 
Thanks for replying though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you set style inside your function `setObjVis`? if not do like following

```
document.getElementById('my_animation').style.visibility = "visible";
```

The pseudocode should be like,

```
function setObjVis ('myObjID') {
   document.getElementById('myObjID').style.visibility = "visible";
}
```

Comment: Although your method worked perfectly (Thanks :) ), I didn't quite understand what you meant by "Have you set inside your function setObjVis?"

Comment: It should be "Have you set style inside your function"... I missed "style"... Sorry, typo :P @Lam2345